# Change Carrierwave upload path to fit Cloud 66's config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, carrierwave, cloud66

Deployed rails app with Cloud 66, to digitalocean.com. Everything works fine, except some permission errors when trying to upload images.

```
 Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /var/deploy/anabol/web_head/releases/20130608104347/public/uploads/tmp):
```

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
...
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
...
end
```

There is a description, how to solve the problem here:
https://www.cloud66.com/help/permission_denied_errors

I changed the store_dir path to:

```
  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

But it didn't help. I still get this error:

```
 » 13:49:25.696 Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /var/deploy/anabol/web_head/releases/20130608114659/public/uploads/tmp):
```

Am I missing something?

### **Edit:**

Upload works with this part in image_uploader.rb:

```
  def cache_dir
    # should return path to cache dir
    Rails.root.join 'tmp/uploads/cache'
  end

  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

But now I get:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/var/deploy/anabol/web_head/releases/20130608164223/tmp/uploads/profile/image/3/thumb_Screenshot_from_2013-06-05_17_27_54.png"):
```

On the view, only the images path is displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are ways to get this working, on hosts where you can upload files.
Two ways are described here, but had some errors, which are now corrected.:
https://www.cloud66.com/help/permission_denied_errors

A working example for a deploy hook, using carrierwave for image-upload:

```
#! /bin/bash
#load environment variables
source /var/.cloud66_env
#assign desired permissions
sudo chmod 0777 -R $RAILS_STACK_PATH/public/uploads
```

## **And the best solution**

(this way you will don't loose the images when redeploy):
use this in your *xy_uploader.rb*:

```
  def store_dir
    "system/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Comment: If anyone needs it, this is what my deploy_hooks.yml file command looks like for permissions management:

`command: chown -R nginx:app_writers $RAILS_STACK_PATH/public/uploads && chmod -R 775 $RAILS_STACK_PATH/public/uploads && sudo chmod -R g+s $RAILS_STACK_PATH/public/uploads`

Answer (score 2):

I checked out Cloud66:

> This user (nginx) does not have elevated permissions, and does not
>   have write access to your filesystem (except explicitly to the /tmp
>   and the $RAILS_STACK_PATH/tmp folders)

This means you can't upload files to be used later to Cloud66 -- you'll want to configure Fog to upload to S3 (or any of fog's cloud file providers).

This is pretty standard among cloud providers. Tutorials:

- http://railgaadi.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/saving-files-in-amazon-s3-using-carrierwave-and-fog-gem/
- http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/Storage/S3.html
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3?view=comments

Comment: I use digitalocean.com, with 30gb ssd, I'm sure I can upload.
Cloud66 only deploys my app there, and their deployment config prevents me to upload, I think. What do you think?